# c# main window and child window

Tags: c#, winforms

If I have a handler over a main window how can I handle the child windows? From processes i can't see the child windows, but on the desktop i see them. Can someone help me to print all the child window that a main window has?

Comment: Hope you mean winforms, Is it Mdi , How are the forms opened, some code would be great to have

Comment: it's not a windows form. It's yahoo messanger for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
Use System.Management;
//Return all processes
public static string ListAllProcesses()
{
    StringBuilder sbAllProcess = new StringBuilder();
    // list out all processes and write them into a stringbuilder
    ManagementClass MgmtClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_Process");

    foreach (ManagementObject mobject in MgmtClass.GetInstances())
    {
        sbAllProcess .Append("Name:\t" + mobject ["Name"] + Environment.NewLine);
        sbAllProcess .Append("ID:\t" + mobject ["ProcessId"] + Environment.NewLine);
        sbAllProcess .Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    return sbAllProcess .ToString();
}
//Return all applications
public static string ListAllApplications()
{
    StringBuilder sbAllApplication = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (Process runningProcess in Process.GetProcesses("."))
    {
        try
        {
            if (runningProcess .MainWindowTitle.Length > 0)
            {
                sbAllApplication .Append("Window Title:\t" + runningProcess .MainWindowTitle.ToString()+ Environment.NewLine);
                sbAllApplication .Append("Process Name:\t" + runningProcess .ProcessName.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                sbAllApplication .Append("Window Handle:\t" + runningProcess .MainWindowHandle.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                sbAllApplication .Append("Memory Allocation:\t" + runningProcess .PrivateMemorySize64.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                sbAllApplication .Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
    return sbAllApplication .ToString();
}
```

Using pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumChildWindows.html Enumchildwindows u will get to know handlers of child window of specific window

Answer (score 0):

**MdiChildren** will give you a set of all forms belonging to a particular form.

Also you can get the forms using **Application.OpenForms**